# What is an appropriate feature extraction for object detection?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Hello I am working on a project that classify objects. I use MLP for this project it can classify an object from 10 different objects. However my accuracy is around %50. I want to improve it, I use 500.000 images as data set so it is more than enough. Right now I am using raw images as input. What is an appropriate feature extraction method for this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The low accuracy may or may not be related to feature extraction by itself. Without it I think your accuracy is still low, I think that is also related to training or other parts. I cannot be specific since you did not give any details. Also for CIFAR-10 I believe you use toronto.edu's dataset and it has 50.000 images not 500.000. Just to prevent confusion.
     Anyhow, for your question there are lots of feature extraction method but I would use Canny Edge Detector. Steps for it:F

- First you have to have GRAYscale images, I assume your images are RGB. In image processing field there are lots of methods to convert rgb to gray image, however, you can choose a method that also Photoshop uses. This conversion method multiples each channel with weight value that human eye perceives the light.
  Gray = (Red * 0.3 + Green * 0.59 + Blue * 0.11)
  Apply it to all your 50.000 images and save outputs in a 3 dimensional matrix.
- Median filtering: Now after first step you need to get rid of the noise. Your GRAYScale images will have a pepper and salt noise, this noise can be an obstacle when detecting the edge of the object, in order to remove this noise use median filter.  When we use median filter we can get good results by eliminating local brightness peaks in the image which distorted by impulse noises and keep the boundaries and shades of an object in the image. Information about the object in the image still remains. Boundaries of the object smoothed perfectly and it does not affected by the filter, which means we can retrieve the edges of the object  without losing any information about the object.

-Last step: Canny Edge Detection. The Canny edge detector usually takes an image in grayscale as input and creates an output image that showing the location of the intensity of the discontinuities.first thing that the Canny edge detector does is that it uses Gaussian convolution to smooth out the input  image and remove noises. Then, the first derivative operator is applied to the smoothed image in order to select those areas of the image which has high first spatial derivatives. The next step that algorithm does that it finds both the magnitude of the gradient and the direction by computing the x-derivative and the y-derivative, these directions of the gradients allows us to find the direction of the edges. After finding the gradient directions, the canny edge detector performs non-maximal suppression which means it tracks the vertex of the ridges that rise from the edges and sets those ridges to zero by producing a thin line as a result. In other words, we check whether the calculated gradient is maximal among the neighboring points that lie in positive and negative gradient directions. If the gradient was the maximum, it will be considered as part of the edge and vice versa.

To sum up use RBG to GRAY, Median Filter and Canny Edge Detector. Note that this process might take more than 5 mins for 50.000 images for a normal computer. So be patient.
Kind regards.

Comment: Yes, I use that data set and it has indeed 50000 images. Sorry for confusion. I will try the method thanks for clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a convolutional neural network for this project instead? CNNs are far superior in image classification compared to MLPs. https://machinelearningmastery.com/when-to-use-mlp-cnn-and-rnn-neural-networks/

Comment: Yes but I have no experience with CNN sadly :(